# Excel Conditional Formatting for 0

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to find the best way to setup conditional formatting for Column A where columns E, G and I = 0

I've attempted to setup a formula based format with the following
`=AND(E2=0,G2=0,I2=0)`

Which kind of works but I'm not sure how to get it to account for the pack numbers in Column A. If the entire range in A matches and E,G and I are at 0 then I want it to highlight them black.

However if there is any differences for that pack then I want the whole range to be left un-highlighted)
(see examples below)

Current output:

[image: Before]

Desired Output:

[image: After]

Is this possible?
Any help would be greatly appreciated!
-Deke

Comment: You could use IF and COUNTIFS to do this I think.

Comment: @BigBen, since it's 0's, couldn't it just be as simple as IF(SUM(rng)=0,T,F)?

Comment: Possibly, depending on OP's data... but that would be SUMIFS, not SUM.

Comment: @BigBen and @Mech I was attempting to use something similar actually `=SUMIFS(D:D,A:A,A2,C:C,"TE") - D2` or even something like `=SUMIFS(D:D,A:A,A2,E:E,0)`. The first option highlights anything that isn't 0 which isn't what I'm looking for the second option highlights everything but the last cell in the duplicate range.

Comment: The rule to get the black highlighting should be using the formula `=COUNTIFS($A:$A,$A2,$E:$E,"<>0",$G:$G,"<>0",$I:$I,"<>0")=0`, I think.

Comment: @BigBen that seems to just highlight the entire column. I've tried different variations of that as well including >0, >=0 and =0 just to see what would happen. No luck so far.

Comment: What is the range that you are applying the conditional format to? Make sure you start in row 2 and not row 1.

Comment: @BigBen the range can be dynamic as each spreadsheet will have a different row count. I'm trying to account for the duplicate ranges that I have in the spreadsheet. Also, I appreciate your help!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use COUNTIFS to count cells containing same pack number and compare it to cells containing same pack number **and** E, G and I equal to 0.

I did a fake dataset like this:

[image]

Notice only packs 2 and 3 got a cell witha  value different to 0 in some row.

My conditional formatting rule is:

```
=COUNTIFS(A:A;A2)=COUNTIFS(A:A;A2;E:E;0;G:G;0;I:I;0)
```

And I get this:

[image]

Comment: Tried to use your rule but comes up with an error. Think it might be the double = you going on? =COUNTIF()=COUNTIF()??

Comment: @Deke that is perfectly valid. If you're having issues, one approach is to first write the formula in a helper column off to the side and get it working there before creating the rule.

Comment: Oh Figured it out you had semi colon instead of coma's. Fixed it and now it looks like it's working. Thanks!! `=COUNTIFS(A:A,A2)=COUNTIFS(A:A,A2,E:E,0,G:G,0,I:I,0)`

Comment: Sorry, readed this right now. True, my separator is the semicolon, not the commas. Glad it worked